# Java process memory is much bigger than specified limits

Tags: java, linux, memory, process

I've researched through most of the methods available to find out how much memory a java process is really using, at all.
So far, I can say I know the total memory allocated could be one or more of the following:

- Heap Memory (supposedly controlled by my -XX:MaxHeapSize=4096m)
- Permanent Memory (supposedly controlled by my -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m)
- Reserved Code Cache (supposedly controlled by my -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m)
- N of Threads * Thread Size (supposedly controlled by my -XX:ThreadStackSize=1024)

But the results are too different from what linux tells me, with any of the methods I found available to get memory consumption of a java process.

In my case it is a Tomcat instance running on a Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64 machine, JVM 1.6_u26 64-bit, and `ps -ALcf | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | wc -l` tells me I have 145 threads or processes running, linked all to the same root process (Tomcat).

That all summed up should give me total max memory of
(4096MB) + (1024MB) + (256MB) + 145 * (1024KB) = 5521MB.
What `jmap -heap PID` tells me, what `ManagementFactory.memoryMXBean.(heapMemoryUsage + nonHeapMemoryUsage).getCommitted()` tells me, and the theoric value above are all on pair.

Now to the linux side, `top` and `nmon` both tells me ResidentMemory allocated by this process is 5.8GB -> roughly 5939,2MB. But I also know this is only part of the memory, the part in live RAM memory. VIRT by `top` and Size by `nmon` (both are supposed to represent the same) tells me the process is 7530MB (or precisely 7710952KB by `nmon`).
This is TOO different from the expected maximum: **2009MB above the maximum**, and according to jmap and jstat the heap memory allocation didn't even reach its peak (2048-OldSpace + 1534-Eden_+_Survivors).

`top` also tells me code stack is 36KB (fair, for the initial catalina starter), and data stack is 7.3GB (representing the rest).

This tomcat server instance is the only one running on this machine, and has been seing some instability. Needs restarting every three days or so, because the machine has 7647544k RAM available, and no swap (for performance reasons). I did the math for the limits, and expecting the process to follow them I saw it was a pretty good security margin to leave for all other services running on the machine (none of which should bother other than ssh and top itself): 7468 - 5521 = 1947. That is almost too much for a "security margin".

So, I want to understand where is all that memory being used from, and why isn't the limit obeyed. If any information is lacking, I'll be happy to provide.

Comment: In your breakdown at the top, you forgot to mention that JNI allocates memory outside of the heap. Is it possible the app you're profiling is using JNI?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to know that for sure (is there?), but I would assume it is not from what I know of the whole application. At least I can assure there is no explicit use of it. The application connects to a external database (not in the same machine),  don't know if that could be using JNI directly. Anyway, the cache of the whole pool is on the other side, on the database side so that should not count.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit jvm process memory on ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145769/limit-jvm-process-memory-on-ubuntu)

Comment: RSS is not same as java heap. VIRT include mmaped files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Plain and simple the JVM uses more memory than what is supplied in `-Xms` and `-Xmx` and the other command line parameters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146775/177800)

Here is a [very detailed article on how the JVM allocates and manages memory](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/), it isn't as simple as what you are expected based on your assumptions in your question, it is well worth a comprehensive read.

ThreadStack size in many implementations have minimum limits that vary by Operating System and sometimes JVM version; the threadstack setting is ignored if you set the limit below the native OS limit for the JVM or the OS ( ulimit on *nix has to be set instead sometimes ). Other command line options work the same way, silently defaulting to higher values when too small values are supplied. Don't assume that all the values passed in represent what are actually used.

The Classloaders, and Tomcat has more than one, eat up lots of memory that isn't documented easily. The JIT eats up a lot of memory, trading space for time, which is a good trade off most of the time.

The numbers you cite are pretty close to what I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and the links, but I still can't accept ~36% of extra memory I just can't controll directly as "what I would expect". Thanks again anyway, I now have some tips on how to lower that number based on some other configs I do on this java process. Other than that, have anything to say about XX:MaxDirectMemorySize ?

Comment: messing with that setting will probably just cause more problems than anything. [The default is 64MB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773775/default-for-xxmaxdirectmemorysize) which is a trivial amount vs the rest of the JVM, much less a Tomcat based application.

Answer (score 3):

The virtual memory is the amount of address space used, something I wouldn't be too concerned about as you have a 64-bit application. The resident is the amount of main memory actually used.

You can add to your list

- shared libraries including the JVM. ~ 0.5 G
- direct memory (0 to 4G) The maximum is the same as the heap maximum by default.
- memory mapped files. No limit.

You can do a `pmap` to show you how much address space is being used for what purpose.

BTW: I have process which is showing 640G VIRT in top due to memory mapped files. It can be alot higher than the resident size. ;)